# How to select a key/value pair with two further keys/values nested inside?

Tags: javascript, json

I am using the below code to iterate through a JSON object which has a dynamic key at the top level.

```
for (var key in data.query.results.json) {
    if(firstSkipped == false)  {
     firstSkipped = true; // sets skipping variable to true so condition is     met on next iteration
    } else {
for (var key2 in data.query.results.json[key]) {
     if(key2 == "http:__purl.org_rss_1.0_title")
    titles.push(data.query.results.json[key][key2].value); // pushes titles to array
```

It works fine however, I need to add another field which is complicating things. The fields below all just have a single value inside them, however, the new field I need to add has a further two keys, each with a value. I need to select just one of these and display the value. I've tried doing the following but I just get 'undefined'.

```
for (var key3 in data.query.results.json[key]) {
        if(key3 == "0")
    isbns.push(data.query.results.json[key][key2][key3].value); // pushes  urls to array
                                }
```

I'm just trying to select the 3rd Key down, then search through each field until it finds the key called '0', then push its value to an array.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong? I can try and post a sample of the JSON if it doesn't make sense without seeing it.

Here is what the data looks like (it is the ISBN field I'm trying to get to):

[image]

Comment: I can't fully understand the issue, I would need a sample data at least. And are you sure that zero is a string and not an integer? Anyway, please try to post a sample json. Also, in the meanwhile, try to take a look to http://underscorejs.org/ : that library can often be really useful in iterating and querying objects/collections.

Comment: I've added an image showing the data. As you can see, the isbn field is an array of two items, whereas all other fields just have the value directly inside them, which is why my code isn't working for this particular field.

Comment: Do you always have titles you can use as keys, like the one above: 'http:__purl.org_rss_1.0_title'? And generally speaking, what's the object and reason of the query? Try to better explain the project, because solutions could be different based on specifications

Comment: I'm taking the data from this object and displaying it on an html page. This is already working but now I have to add an extra field for the ISBN. I've explained clearly above why adding the isbn isn't simply a matter of copying the code for another field and changing it.

Comment: ah, I saw 'umbria' on strings above

Comment: But you checked for "http:__purl.org_rss_1.0_title" above. Anyway, too difficult for me to really understand your needs. Though, for searching in objects I strongly suggest you to use underscore's methods, like find, findWhere, each, an the like... You'll find them really usefull.

Comment: Thanks - I'll look into that.

Comment: It's a really tiny library, easy, well documented and really well tested, so you'll be happy with it. Hope it will speed up your work.

Comment: Another question: is that json data native, or are you converting from an xml document?

Comment: It turns out the reason my code didn't work is because the ISBNs are held in an array, which can't be access using [key] as this is for objects only.

Comment: Are you sure? normally arrays in javascript are accessible with keys just like objects (in fact, array.keyname is the same as array['keyname']). After all, in javascript arrays are just objects with some different native functions.